# trouble getting all menu > li in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have a few navigations on 1 page which look like this:

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li>link here</li>
 <li>Link Here</li>
</div>
```

I have 2 or 3 on one page.

I am trouble making them go into a select and options box in jquery.

It works 100% if i only have 1 on a page but because i have 2 or 3 of them on a page sometimes it only inputs the first menu into all dropdown select boxes.

Here is the jquery:

```
jQuery("<select />").appendTo(".menu");
    jQuery("<option />", {"selected": "selected","value"   : "","text" : "Navigation Menu"}).appendTo(".menu select");
    jQuery(".menu ul li a").each(function() {

        var el = jQuery(this);
        jQuery("<option />", {"value"   : el.attr("href"),"text"    : el.text()}).appendTo(".menu select");
    });

    jQuery(".menu select").change(function() {

        window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
```

I know its meant to look something like this but its just throwing errors.

```
jQuery("<select />").appendTo(".menu");
    jQuery("<option />", {"selected": "selected","value"   : "","text" : "Navigation Menu"}).appendTo(".menu select");

    var showlis = 'ul li a';
    jQuery(this + showlis).each(function() {

        var el = jQuery(this);
        jQuery("<option />", {"value"   : el.attr("href"),"text"    : el.text()}).appendTo(".menu select");
    });

    jQuery(".menu select").change(function() {

        window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
    });
```

Comment: adding whitespace to all of those lines does not mean that `this` is bound to the context of `.menu`

Comment: This is a very bad quality and very confusing post. You have no valid example HTML. the `</ul>` is missing, there are no `a` elements anywhere yet you reference them in your script "ul li a", where are they? Please post Html which applies to the script you are posting. As it currently stands the script does not apply to the posted HTML and makes no sense.

Comment: @jbabey there is white space because i have made it more readable for you guys, there is not white space in my file.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl This was just a demo of the code, not exact, the html is not the question asked. It was about the jquery.

Comment: @RobertGouveia: then remove the HTML if it doesn't apply and has no relation to the script as it only makes the question confusing!

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - it was there just to show how i was creating the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to each `.menu` item individually instead of referring to it via the class alone.

What the code below does is:

> For each `.menu` in your DOM (page)
>
> 1. Create and append a `<select>` onto it
> 2. Add a default `<option>` element
> 3. Loop through the `<li>`s and a corresponding `<option>` inside the `<select>`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/5dm37/

**Code:**

```
$('.menu').each(function() {
    var menu = $(this);
    var sel = $("<select />").appendTo(menu);
    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Navigation Menu"
    }).appendTo(sel);
    menu.find('li').each(function() {
        $("<option />", {
            "value": $(this).attr("href"),
            "text": $(this).text()
        }).appendTo(sel);
    });
    sel.change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you this was nearly 100%, the only problem is the when a li has a child it does not list the child within it, instead it joins it with the option box, if you understand what i mean?

Comment: oh.. ok. so if you have li -> .. -> li1 -> .. -> li2 - the corresponding option should be like "li li1 li2", instead of as separate options?

Comment: I am sorry i did not understand what you meant, i do appriciate your time in trying to help though, thank you.

Comment: Np. It helps my experience too.. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by child li's not being separate options, but joining the option created for the parent element?

Comment: If you go to http://jsfiddle.net/robert1981/etLdx/1/ you can see that the html it has child lists within a list on one menu. But on the live run when you click on the select box you can see that it works great apart from on the parent list it shows the child lists in the option, it also shows then under as it is meant too. but its not meant to show within the parent one.

Comment: But `<select>` cannot be nested. the best that can be done is showing it in a different `<select>` altogether.

Comment: I dont mean nest the select. The original version i had which can be seen: http://jsfiddle.net/robert1981/8YAvy/3/  works 100% but when you add another menu it does not work

Comment: Ok, so all it needs to do is no consider the nested ul's or li's while constructing the <select> - Thats should be straight forward. A few secs..

Answer (score 0):

All of the jQuery manipulation functions outside of clone move elements.

http://api.jquery.com/category/Manipulation/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DManipulation%26redirect%3Dno

This means that for each menu class div you need to create a new element. Creating one element will append it to the first menu class div.

EX:

```
$(".menu").each( function(index, element) {
    //Create select and options here
    $(element).append(SELECT);
});
```

Comment: I cant do that, because wordpress only give 1 static class, and i cant update everytime i input a new menu.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I notice:

1. Not sure if it's just a copy-paste error, but in your navigation menu, you don't have a closing `<ul>` tag. This is invalid HTML.
2. **This is likely your problem.** You are appending your new `<select />` tag to an element found with the jQuery selector `.menu`. That selector matches all elements with the `menu` class. It doesn't know *which* element with the menu class that you're trying to append it to, so it *probably* just appends it to the first one every time. You will need to narrow down your selector. The best way to do this would probably be to give each navigation `<div>` an `id` attribute and use that as your selector.
3. I'm very confused as to why you would want to do this at all. You already have the list for your navigation, why are you trying to put dropdowns in there as well?

Comment: It was a quick show of the html, it was a typo thats all, its not in the real content. The reason i want to do this is because wordpress only give 1 static css class for multipul menus on a page and when it goes into mobile format i want it so all menus are within the select boxes instead of having a long scroll of menu items